# How to enable a Uialertview specific button in iOS after it is clicked, using Swift?

Tags: swift

[image]

on Button clear history I want to enable other 2 buttons. I am new in iOS.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    let markAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Mark as Urgent", style: .default, handler: { (action) in   

    })
     let resolveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Resolvethe conversion", style: .default, handler: { (action) in

    })
     markAction.isEnabled = false
    resolveAction.isEnabled = false
    alert.addAction(markAction)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Clear history", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        alert.actions.map {$0.isEnabled = true}
    }))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: How did you disabled it?

Comment: Share some of you code so that we can look into that

Comment: Note that `UIAlertView` is long-deprecated. Your supposed to use `UIAlertController` instead.

Comment: @AbhirajsinhThakore herei share the code..

Answer (score 1):

You can enable your actions in the clear button completion handler and present again your alert because you cannot avoid the dismiss:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
let markAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Mark as Urgent", style: .default, handler: { (action) in

    // TODO: Your action

})

markAction.isEnabled = false
alert.addAction(markAction)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Clear history", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
    alert.actions.map {$0.isEnabled = true}
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}))

self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```